# Free double array char without free string

Tags: c, arrays

I'm looking to realloc a double char array without free string in it, here is my code :

```
char **rea_scd_array(char **src, int add)
{
    char **ret;
    int  i;

    i = 0;
    while (src[i] != '\0')
        i++;
    ret = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * (i + add + 1));
    ret[i + add] = '\0';
    while (i >= 0)
    {
        ret[i] = &src[i][0];
        i--;
    }
    free(&src);
    return (ret);
}
```

My idea is to add new dimension to store string in it without realloc all table of the array and duplicate all old content.

My code isn't working, I get

```
`"malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff5fbff9e8: pointer being freed was not allocated
 set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug"`
```

I'm just looking to free the second array dimension who store pointer to string.

Any idea ?

Comment: Good English but horrible indentation..

Comment: Your English is not that bad. :)

Comment: [Please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Comment: Style hints: 1) Set your editor to use four spaces instead of tabs for indenting. Tabs are *asking* for trouble. 2) *Always* use `{}` for the body of `if` or `while`, even if it's a single line. 3) Don't cast the return value of `malloc()`.

Comment: My idea is to NOT realloc all the array, realloc is heavy

Comment: Your description is extremely vague and unclear. There are two plausible options to what you are trying to do: 1. Take a an array of characters and extend it to contain more characters. 2. Take a an array of strings and extend it to contain more strings. Your entire code is wrong in either case. BTW, in both cases, you can simply use `realloc`.

Comment: Im looking to exetend a array of strings to contain more strings! I cannot use realloc! forget it. My idea is to make a realloc like without dumping string, I want to use string address not to copy string

Comment: free(&src); Did you mean free(src)??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation compels you to add a `NULL` pointer at the end of the array.

The following lines of code are making me doubt that this is what you meant to do:

```
while (src[i] != '\0')
ret[i + add] = '\0';
```

If it was `NULL` instead of `'\0'` then I would think otherwise (although they are essentially identical).

In addition to that, using `add` larger than 1 will get you an array which contains some "junk pointers".

Anyway, at this point we have two options (excluding `realloc`):

1. Use a `NULL` pointer in order to indicate the end of the array.
2. Use a `len` variable in order to indicate the length of the array.

The second option is more efficient, so you would be better off with that.

Option #1:

```
char **rea_scd_array(char **src, int add)
{
    char **ret;
    int  i;
    int  len = 0;
    while (src[len] != NULL)
        len++;
    ret = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * (len + add + 1));
    for (i=0; i<len; i++)
        ret[i] = src[i];
    for (; i<len+add+1; i++)
        ret[i] = NULL; // necessary in order for this function to work correctly
    free(src);
    return ret;
}
```

Option #2:

```
char **rea_scd_array(char **src, int len, int add)
{
    char **ret;
    int  i;
    ret = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * (len + add));
    for (i=0; i<len; i++)
        ret[i] = src[i];
    for (; i<len+add; i++)
        ret[i] = NULL; // necessary for other functions that are using this array
    free(src);
    return ret;
}
```

In both cases, you'll need to allocate the initial array and fill it with `NULL` pointers, outside this function.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to free `src` to which you never allocated memory, in the first place. You free the memory that you allocated dynamically to the heap (typically through `malloc`).

Comment: I call this function with a double chars array which is created by strsplit. So array is allocated :)
My free is bad but didn't understood why

Comment: @insidelulz Are you sure you are allocating memory not only to your `char **src` but also to each string each of these pointers point to?

Comment: Yes is it, my src array is generated by strsplit

Answer (score 0):

If you dont know the size beforehand and you don't want to `realloc`, use a singly linked list:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    char *data;
    struct node *next;
} t_node;

extern char *strdup(const char *);

t_node *insert(t_node *node, char *s)
{
    t_node *new = malloc(sizeof(*new));

    if (new == NULL) {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    new->data = strdup(s);
    if (new->data == NULL) {
        perror("strdup");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    new->next = NULL;
    if (node != NULL) node->next = new;
    return new;
}

int main(void)
{
    t_node *temp, *first, *node = NULL;

    node = first = insert(node, "First");
    node = insert(node, "Second");
    node = insert(node, "Third");
    node = insert(node, "Last");
    node = first;
    while (node) {
        printf("%s\n", node->data);
        temp = node->next;
        free(node->data);
        free(node);
        node = temp;
    }
    return 0;
}
```